# One way repeated measures ANCOVA?

Tags: ancova

Hi  Is it possible to run a repeated measures one way ANCOVA?

My data is from a cross-over design study, each subject followed 3 different diets.
I can see from a repeated measures ANOVA that there is an effect of the diets on sweat rate (continuous variable). But i think this is influenced by resting core temperature. So i have this measured also across the 3 different conditions in each individual. Can i run a one-way repeated measures ANCOVA to account for the differences in resting core temperature?
I'm running the analysis in SPSS as the 3 diets as the within-subject variable, and sweat rate as the measure, with the 3 core temperatures in as  Covariates.

If the test of within-subject effects is p<0.05 for diet (sphericity assumed) (as it was with the one way repeated measures ANOVA).
The 3 different diet*resting temperature within subject effects are all p>0.05. 
Therefore the resting temperature is not impacting sweat rate...?

Or i actually think this should really be a 2 way repeated measures anova? 
sorry for the basic questions, I'm new to this.